# Why do people bite their nails even when they do not want to?

Tags: cognitive-psychology

Why do people bite their nails? People seem to be doing it primarily while contemplating something, or during problem-solving tasks. They seem to understand it is a bad habit, and sometimes they seem to try to active avoid it, but keep on doing it nonetheless so it seems. Why does this happen?

Comment: Welcome to Cognitive Sciences. Self-help questions are discouraged here and I have attempted to re-word your question by deleting any reference to self.

Answer (score 2):

Nail-biting is considered a **parafunctional habit**. A parafunctional habit is the habitual exercise of a body part in a way that isn't the way that that part was intended to be used. Other common parafunctional habits include bruxism (grinding of teeth), hair-pulling, and picking at skin.

Nobody knows what causes these habits. Possible physical or psychological causes may include emotions (aggression, anxiety, stress, tension), hyperactivity, complications from other disorders (such as obsessive-compulsive disorder), or as a coping or focus mechanism, similar to how babies and young children find it soothing to suck on their thumbs.